# Bootstrap responsivo exemplos por favor

Tags: html, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Olá, sou ingressante nesse mundo de freameworks, e tenho muita dificuldade, eu gostaria que alguém pode-se me dar um exemplo simples de div responsiva, que se adapte a alguns tamanhos de tela usando o bootstrap, fazendo alguns comentários sobre as classes usadas. Digo isso pois, ainda não encontrei na internet algum lugar que explicasse com exemplos práticos, normalmente é algo muito teórico, somente com a sintaxe e as funções do framework...

Comment: Qual versão Bootstrap você está usando?

Comment: Podes ver a [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com.br) em Português.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O framework Bootstrap CSS possui diversos utilitários de responsabilidade, explicados de forma básica a seguir:

No Bootstrap CSS existe o mecanismo chamado 'grid', que nada mais é que distribuir a estrutura html em uma grade, que contém linha `(classe .row)` e colunas dentro desta linha `(classes col-*-*)`, funciona como no exemplo a seguir:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
      <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse exemplo breve abre margem pra explicar sobre os classnames de colunas e os utilitários de responsabilidade, os definidores de colunas são definidos da seguinte maneira:

'.col-tamanhoDoDispositivo-numeroDeColunas'

Sendo o tamanho dos dispositivos:

- **xs** : Extra Small -> Para mobile
- **sm** : Small -> Para tablets
- **md** : Medium -> Para desktop
- **lg** : Large -> Para telas grandes

E número de colunas podendo variar entre 1 e 12, sempre somando 12 por linha, caso ultrapasse, como citado na documentação oficial:

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

Ela receberá a proprioedade `wrap` e as colunas que sobram e/ou fazem parte do elemento com mais de 12 passará a fazer parte da linha seguinte, como no exemplo a seguir:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">.col-xs-9</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4<br>Sendo 9 + 4 = 13 &gt; 12, está coluna de valor 4 será quebrada como se fizesse parte de uma nova linha.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6<br>Colunas subsequentes permanecem na próxima coluna.</div>
</div>
```

Outra coisa importante a respeito de divs responsivas, são os utilitários, que servem para ocultar ou mostrar elementos de acordo com o dispositivo, esses classnames devem ser adicionados ao elemento que deverá receber sua propriedade e são os seguintes:

**Visibilidate:**

- .visible-xs-*
- .visible-sm-*
- .visible-md-*
- .visible-ls-*

Esses utilitários de responsabilidade podem receber como parte do valor `(no lugar do *)`:

- -block
- -inline
- -inline-block

Os tamanhos são os mesmo indicados para o tamanho da div, ou seja, `'.visible-xs-block'` irá exibir em resoluções mobile, e assim com as outras.

**Ocultamento:**

- .hidden-xs-*
- .hidden-sm-*
- .hidden-md-*
- .hidden-ls-*

Da mesma forma como para exibir, podemos ocultar de acordo com o dispositivo, ou seja, `'.hidden-md'` irá ocultar determinado elemento para resoluções padrões de desktop.

Para finalizar, ainda dentro de definições de responsabilidade, podemos indicar a propriedade `offset`, que tem como função indicar que deve ser pulada determinada quantidade de colunas em uma `div`:

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
</div>
```

**______________________________________________________**

Todos os exemplos citados na resposta foram tirados diretamente da página oficial do framework em [CSS - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid).

Recomendações de material:

[Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/) - Biblioteca de temas simples

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp) - Exemplos fáceis e testáveis

[Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) - Documentação Oficial

Answer (score 0):

Vou listar aqui alguns exemplo legais que encontrei:

**EXEMPLO 1**

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="panel">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Legend</legend>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                            Option one
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="panel">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Legend</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail">
                            Email address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[**EXEMPLO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

E o mais importante, sobre não localizar documentação de qualidade para seu objetivo, acredito que o você vai gostar bastantes deste material [aqui](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-html-css-javascript/bootstrap-e-formularios-html5/#10-14-grid-responsivo-do-bootstrap), os exemplo não só são práticos como testáveis.